# If $X \sim \mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$, what is the distribution of $X$ conditioned on the event $\|X\| \le r$?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Let $\Sigma$ be a $p$-by-$p$ positive-definite matrix and let $r > 0$. Let $X \sim \mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$ and $R = R(X):= \|X\|$.

> **Quesion.** What is the distribution of $X$ conditioned on the event $R \le r$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Bayes' Theorem we can write:

$p(X | \| X \| \le r) \propto p(\| X \| \le r | X) p(X) = 1_{\{ \| X \| \le r\}} (x) \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)(x)$.

If $X$ is given and $r$ is a given constant, then there is nothing random in the expression $p(\| X \| \le r | X)$, so this is just an indicator function $1_{\{ \| X \| \le r\}}$ equal to 1 if $\| X \| \le r$ and 0 otherwise, so the distribution is one proportional to a normal distribution times the indicator function, making the distribution a truncated multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Sure, should've thought of that before posting. Thanks! Anyways, the normalization constant will going to be nasty, involving incomplete gamma functions...

Comment: More precisely, the normalization constant should be $P(\|X\| \le r) = \frac{\gamma(p/2,r^2/(2\sigma^2))}{\Gamma(p/2)}$, where $(a,x) \mapsto \gamma(a,x) := \int_{0}^x e^{-t}t^{a-1}dt$ is the lower incomplete gamma function and $a \mapsto \Gamma(a):=\gamma(a,\infty)$ is the usual gamma function.